# Adding an Array's elements to last element and compare it with another Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having two array with the same length and format given at the end.
assume the last element on each array is the score if either array has zero values in other elements.

Let's say we have array p1 and p2 each have 7 elements. If either p1 or p2 first 6 elements has zero value then it means the game is over and we sum up all other elements and add to last element(mail_hole) which define its score. Then compare each score to find the winner.

Here is my code:

```js
function checkWinner(holes, status = "incomplete", winner = "none") {
  const p1MainHole = holes["p1"].pop(); // check if all holes has zero stone.(Except main hole)
  const p2MainHole = holes["p2"].pop(); // check if all holes has zero stone.(Except main hole)
  if (holes["p1"].every((hole) => hole.value === 0)) {
    const sumOfAllStone = this.countAllStone(holes, "p2", p2MainHole);
    holes["p2"].push(sumOfAllStone);
    holes["p1"].push(p1MainHole);
    status = "complete";
  } else if (holes["p2"].every((hole) => hole.value === 0)) {
    const sumOfAllStone = this.countAllStone(holes, "p1", p1MainHole);
    holes["p1"].push(sumOfAllStone);
    holes["p2"].push(p2MainHole);
    status = "complete";
  } else {
    holes["p1"].push(p1MainHole);
    holes["p2"].push(p2MainHole);
  }
  if (status === "complete") {
    winner = holes["p1"][holes["p1"].length - 1].value > holes["p2"][holes["p2"].length - 1].value ? "p1" : "p2";
  }
  return {
    holes,
    status,
    winner
  };
}


function countAllStone(holes, player, mainHole) {
  for (let i = 0; i < holes[player].length; i++) {
    mainHole.value += holes[player][i].value;
  }
  return mainHole;
}

console.log(
    checkWinner({
        p1: [
            {
                name: "hole_0",
                value: 0,
            },
            {
                name: "hole_1",
                value: 0,
            },
            {
                name: "hole_2",
                value: 0,
            },
            {
                name: "hole_3",
                value: 0,
            },
            {
                name: "hole_4",
                value: 0,
            },
            {
                name: "hole_5",
                value: 0,
            },
            {
                name: "main_hole",
                value: 0,
            },
        ],
        p2: [
            {
                name: "hole_0",
                value: 1,
            },
            {
                name: "hole_1",
                value: 1,
            },
            {
                name: "hole_2",
                value: 1,
            },
            {
                name: "hole_3",
                value: 1,
            },
            {
                name: "hole_4",
                value: 2,
            },
            {
                name: "hole_5",
                value: 0,
            },
            {
                name: "main_hole",
                value: 1,
            },
        ],
    })
);
```

At the end it compares each player's score(last elements) to find the winner.

I am not satisfied with the amount of code written and the efficiency of it. Any idea would be welcome, Thanks.

Comment: "My code actually works": that makes it off topic here. Unless you have a *problem* with the current efficiency? Is there any reason you believe the efficiency is not good?

Comment: As to the algorithm: is it intended that you don't check the zeroes of the other player in case the first player has all zeroes? Shouldn't the main hole of the other player still be updated?

Comment: Yes, I do it that way if you check the code.

Comment: I checked the code, and you don't check whether the second player has all zeroes when the first player has all zeroes. They both could be in that situation, but your code only updates one of the player's score, not both. Also, the `countAllStone` does not first reset the main hole's value. Is it indended that this accumulates when `countAllStone` is called later again?

Comment: To add on to @trincot's comment above in regards to `countAllStone`, the `p2` array has an existing `main_hole` value as `1`. Since the method `countAllStone` does not initialize, the values of the other elements are added to this `1`, thus updating it to `7`. If initialized to zero, this value will be calculated to be `6`.

Comment: *"I am not satisfied with ... the efficiency of it."*: Please provide evidence that the efficiency is unsatisfactory. I don't see any problem with its efficiency. If this is not your experience, please provide evidence that shows that there is a problem there.

Comment: @trincot 1: No possibility that both player has zero elements so checking one means the game is finished(completed with the winner). 2: The last element is the score of the game until one player has all zero element except last elements. Lets say *p1 = [0,0,0,2 ]* and *p2 = [1,1,1,4]* then *p1 score = 2* and *p2 score =7* which means game is completed and winner is *p2*. Thus last element's score is added to sum of other elements.

Comment: @jsN00b last element's value is important because *score = last element + sum of other elements*

Comment: I think I couldnt explain the question very well so sorry about that. But I be grateful if you found any mistake or problem in code.

Comment: Is it possible that `p1` will be `[0, 0, 0, main_hole: 7]` and `p2` will be `[1, 1, 1, main_hole: 2]`? If yes, then `p2` is the winner, correct? Because although `p1` main_hole (`7`) is greater than `p2` main_hole (`5` = `1 + 1 + 1 +2`), because `p1` had `0`'s in first-three, automatically `p2` is winner. Also: is it possible to have `p1` = `[1, 1, 1, 3]` and `p2` = `[1, 1, 1, 3]`? How about `p1` = `[1, 1, 1, 6]` and `p2` = `[1, 1, 1, 2]`? May I please understand who is the winner in last-two cases & why.

Comment: No, in your first case, *P1 is the winner because P1's main_hole = 7* and *P2's main_hole + 3 = 5*.

Comment: Winner is chosen not because of zeros but because of the sum of elements and the mail_hole. Zero values means that the game is over  but winner is selected by the score of each player

Comment: For your 2nd case: *p1 = [1, 1, 1, 6] and p2 = [1, 1, 1, 2]* This game is not finished yet until any p1 pr p2 has all zero value elements. Hope this is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be one possible alternate solution to achieve the desired objective:

**Code Sample**

```
  if (allZeroValues(p1) || allZeroValues(p2)) {
    resObj.status = 'complete';
    if (allZeroValues(p1)) updateTotal(p2);
    else updateTotal(p1);
    resObj.winner = getWinner(p1, p2);
  };
```

**Explanation**

- if either `p1` or `p2` are zero-valued (except 'main_hole'), then
- set `status` to complete
- if `p1` is all zeroes, update `p2`'s total
- else, update `p1`'s total
- set `winner` based on the totals

There are several helper methods used which may be understood from perusing the snippet below.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const checkWinner = (holes, status = "incomplete", winner = "none") => {
  // first, declare few helper methods
  
  // to get an array without the 'main_hole'
  const skipMainHole = arr => ([
    ...arr.filter(el => el.name !== 'main_hole')
  ]);
  
  // add total values except 'main_hole'
  const sumValues = arr => (
    skipMainHole(arr).reduce(
      (tot, itm) => (tot + itm.value),
      0
    )
  );
  
  // check if array without 'main_hole' is all zeroes
  // assumption: 'value' will always be non-negative integer
  const allZeroValues = arr => (sumValues(arr) === 0);
  
  // update 'main_hole' value
  const updateTotal = arr => {
    arr[arr.length - 1].value += sumValues(arr);
  };
  
  // get winner
  const getWinner = (arr1, arr2) => (
    arr1.slice(-1)[0].value === arr2.slice(-1)[0].value
      ? 'none'
      : arr1.slice(-1)[0].value > arr2.slice(-1)[0].value
        ? 'p1'
        : 'p2'
  );
  
  // now, de-structure holes to get the p1, p2 arrays
  const {p1, p2} = holes;
  // set-up a result-object
  const resObj = {status, winner};
  
  // now, for the actual logic
  if (allZeroValues(p1) || allZeroValues(p2)) {
    resObj.status = 'complete';
    if (allZeroValues(p1)) updateTotal(p2);
    else updateTotal(p1);
    resObj.winner = getWinner(p1, p2);
  };
  
  // finally, return the updated result-object
  return {...resObj, holes: {p1, p2}};
};

console.log(
    checkWinner({
        p1: [
            {
                name: "hole_0",
                value: 0,
            },
            {
                name: "hole_1",
                value: 0,
            },
            {
                name: "hole_2",
                value: 0,
            },
            {
                name: "hole_3",
                value: 0,
            },
            {
                name: "hole_4",
                value: 0,
            },
            {
                name: "hole_5",
                value: 0,
            },
            {
                name: "main_hole",
                value: 0,
            },
        ],
        p2: [
            {
                name: "hole_0",
                value: 1,
            },
            {
                name: "hole_1",
                value: 1,
            },
            {
                name: "hole_2",
                value: 1,
            },
            {
                name: "hole_3",
                value: 1,
            },
            {
                name: "hole_4",
                value: 2,
            },
            {
                name: "hole_5",
                value: 0,
            },
            {
                name: "main_hole",
                value: 1,
            },
        ],
    })
);
```